# Issued changing the navigationbar image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Currently, I am able to change the tint of the my `UINavigationBar` by

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0f green:74/255.0f blue:74/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

However when I try to implement the following code to change the image of the `UINavigationBar` all together, I see no results..

```
 UIImage *navImageBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"texturedNav"] //This being my .png image
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];



    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navImageBackground
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably calling the appearance delegate after the navigation bar is already on screen so your request is being 'ignored'. Or, at least, not causing a UI update.

Set the appearance before the navigation bar is shown. Or, force a UI refresh by hiding and showing the navigation bar (without animation).